# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, poo, php7, pdo, xampp

Vi una pregunta similar pero el código es distinto, honestamente no se como resolver este problema. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Aqui esta la conexión con todos los parametros necesarios para poder realizar la conexion

```
<?php 
class Conexion{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $db = "db_sistema";
    private $conect;

    public function __construct(){
       
        $connectionString = "mysql:host".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db.";charset=utf8;";
        try {
            $this->conect = new PDO($connectionString, $this->user, $this->password);
            $this->conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch ( Exception $e) {
            $this->conect = "Error de conexion";
            echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function conect(){
        return $this->conect;
    }
}

?>
```

Aqui diseño una clase usuario para poder realizar la conexion y ejecutar la sentencia preparada, ademas en el metodo constructor se accede a la conexion

```
<?php
require_once("Autoload.php");
class Usuario extends Conexion{
    private $strNombre;
    private $strPass;
    private $strEmail;
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conexion = new Conexion();
        $this->conexion = $this->conexion->conect();
    }

    public function insertUsuario(string $nombre, string $email, string $pass){
        $this->strNombre = $nombre;
        $this->strPass = $pass;
        $this->strEmail = $email;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO proy_user(nombre, contraseña, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $insert = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $arrData = array($this->strNombre, $this->strPass, $this->strEmail);
        $insert->execute($arrData);
    }
}
?>
```

Aqui hago una instancia para poder ejecutar la sentencia preparada

```
<?php
require_once("Autoload.php");
$objUs = new Usuario();
// insert
$objUs->insertUsuario("Nraya", "mail@mail.com", "1234");
// echo $insert;
?>
```

Al final cuando ejecuto el codigo principal me arroja este error, me dice que no se reconoce la base de datos seleccionada pero hice una prueba solo con el archivo de conexion y todo estaba bien

Aqui dejo una imagen, la base de datos si existe, ya habia hecho una prueba y la conexion estaba bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. En `$connectionString` solo tienes `mysql:host`; te hace falta agregar el `=` mira si con eso queda; debe ser `mysql:host=` y lo demás que tienes.

Comment: Vaya, me cicle tanto que no me di cuenta. Gracias, tendré que borrar la pregunta, era un error semántico. Muchas gracias Roberto!!

Comment: Dos advertencias sobre tu clase: 1. No conviene en ningún caso mostrar al usuario errores internos como haces en `echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();` De hecho, un problema que tiene PDO es que, si algo falla, en el mensaje de error se revela el nombre de usuario y la contraseña. 2. Para un uso amplio de tu clase envoltorio, convendría que la misma extendiese de PDO, de lo contrario, cualquier método propio de PDO que necesites no podrás usarlo con instancias de `Conexion` a no ser que lo re-escribas en la clase.